# Incorrect volume usage in FSx for ONTAP

Tags: storage, file-storage, amazon-fsx, ontap, block-storage

I have an AWS FSx for ONTAP (https://aws.amazon.com/fsx/netapp-ontap/) volume that is 2TB in size and I have only ingested a little bit of data.
However my application is reporting that a lot more data has been used.

To troubleshoot I ran a "df -h" command and it says that "used" is 981G but I have only written a few GBs to the volume.

ubuntu@ip-10-0-2-228:/mnt/vol1_stem_prod$ df -h .
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
10.0.3.181:/vol_stem_prod  2.0T  981G  965G  51% /mnt/vol1_stem_prod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default a volume that is over-provisioned reports the underlying aggregate available space.
Set the volume to use logical volume reporting with the following command:

```bash
Fsx::> volume modify -vserver <vserver_name> -volume <vol_name> -is-space-reporting-logical true
Volume modify successful on volume <vol_name> of Vserver <vserver_name>.
```

This is what the user will see after changing this setting:

```bash
$ df -h .
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
10.0.3.181:/your_vol  2.0T  3.1G  1.9T   1% /mnt/your_vol
```